# Need to update hashtable after each call

Tags: c#, hashtable

I need to update my hashtable after each `printout()` method call, but whenever i do, it just shows the latest added thing, not the entire hashtable that i have already added values to.

Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int NOP = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("How many people to gift?");

        NOP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int i=0;i<NOP;i++)
        {
            printout(NOP);
            NOP--;
        }
        Hashtable hashtable= printout(NOP);
        foreach (string key in hashtable.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", key, hashtable[key]));
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
```

hashtable method:

```
    public static Hashtable printout(int NOP)
    {
        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

        string[] names = new string[50];
        int[] FriendsMoney = new int[50];
        string GiftGiver = "";
        int AmountGifted = 0;
        int AmountDivider = 0;
        string[] GiftRecievers = new string[50];

        //input



        //----print names-----//
        Console.WriteLine("Names of the " + NOP + " people?");

        for (int i = 0; i < NOP; i++)
        {
            names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //-----gift giver----//
        Console.WriteLine("Who is the gift giver?");

        GiftGiver = Console.ReadLine();

        //-------AmountGifted------------//
        Console.WriteLine("Amount to gift?");

        AmountGifted = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        //--------AmountDivided----------//
        Console.WriteLine("How many people to divide gift among?");

        AmountDivider = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        //----------Gift Recievers----------//
        Console.WriteLine("Names of gift recievers?");

        for (int i = 0; i < AmountDivider; i++)
        {
            GiftRecievers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        AmountGifted = AmountGifted / AmountDivider;


        for (int i = 0; i < AmountDivider; i++)
        {

            hashtable.Add(GiftRecievers[i], AmountGifted);

        }

        return hashtable;

    }
```

What i want is to keep the old values and update them if the key is used.

Comment: Hashtable is a legacy class from .net 1.1 you should be using Dictionary instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you are using the same Key in `GiftRecievers[i] = Console.ReadLine();` to be used with `hashtable.Add(GiftRecievers[i], AmountGifted);`.

Use the function `hashtable.ContainsKey(GiftRecievers[i])` the check if the Key is already added. If it was added the Hashtable replace the current item with the new `AmountGifted`.

Use an iterator to see how many items are stored into your HashTable instead of using `foreach(string key in hashtable.Keys)`:

```
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in hashtable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", de.Key, hashtable.Value);
    }
```

Also, include in your question a Console Output to show how many data are you enter as keys and values.

**UPDATE:** Each time that you are calling `public static Hashtable printout(int NOP)` you are creating a new instance of HashTable. If you want use the same Hast table modify your function to receive a HashTable instance as reference, like this:

```
public static void printout(ref HashTable hashtable, int NOP)
{
    //Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable(); //It is passed as an argument

    string[] names = new string[50];
    //...

    for (int i = 0; i < AmountDivider; i++)
    {

        hashtable.Add(GiftRecievers[i], AmountGifted);

    }
   //return hashtable; //remove the return.
}
```

Mean while, in the `main` create the Hashtable instance and pass it referenced argument:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

    int NOP = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("How many people to gift?");

    NOP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for(int i=0;i<NOP;i++)
    {
        printout(ref hashtable, NOP);
        NOP--;
    }

    printout(ref hashtable, NOP);

    foreach (string key in hashtable.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", key, hashtable[key]));
    }
    Console.Read();

}
```

Comment: there is 0 reason to use `ref` here you never do `hashtable = ...` inside the function. just using `hastable.` does not require `ref`.